# Create anchor tags and links from div ID value in JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large site, and most of the places have anchor links with icons. When I hit the icon, it will take us to its section within the same page. So, creating anchor links and replacing them with id values is a lot of manual work, so I want to use simple code and not any plugins.

I have illustrated it with a sample code below. I hope it's self-explanation. If any details are needed, I am happy to provide them. JavaScript or PHP is totally fine.

```
<div class="" id="process-invoices">
  <a href="#{link-should-be-from-above-div-id}">My Icon, No text</a>
</div>
<div class="" id="plan-payments">
  <a href="#{link-should-be-from-above-div-id}">My Icon, No text</a>
</div>
<div class="" id="make-payments">
  <a href="#{link-should-be-from-above-div-id}">My Icon, No text</a>
</div>
<div class="" id="track-performance">
  <a href="#{link-should-be-from-above-div-id}">My Icon, No text</a>
</div>
```

I have tried other examples but not getting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can select all the divs and then find the anchor tag inside it for each div and set its `href` attribute to the `id` of the div.

```
// Select all divs
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

// Loop through each div
divs.forEach(function(div) {
    // Get the id of the div
    var id = div.id;

    // Find the anchor tag inside the div
    var anchor = div.querySelector('a');

    // Set the href of the anchor tag to the id of the div
    anchor.href = '#' + id;
});
```

Comment: Amazing!! @Karl Hill...It's working perfect. One addition to this. Can I also create anchor tag from Javascript itself the way you created link? So I will just leave with image for icon.

Comment: Sure, in the forEach add: anchor.innerHTML = 'My Icon, No text';
div.appendChild(anchor);

Comment: Excellent  !! Thank you for the quick response  faster than AI